# Default values are being used for My.Settings instead of those in the app.config (for a Windows service)

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, application-settings

A Windows service written in VB.NET is using the My.Settings namespace for simplicity. There are only three settings to read, and these are read within the constructor of the ServiceLauncher.

I am attempting to install the service as such:

```
installutil GID.ServiceLauncher.exe
```

And this is successful, however the config settings it is using are not the ones within the GID.ServiceLauncher.exe.config file, instead it is using the ones baked into the app as Default Settings within Settings.Designer.vb (marked with DefaultSettingValueAttribute). *[The questionable wisdom of Microsoft not allowing a developer to ignore default settings is another question entirely]*.

How can I further diagnose this issue, and maybe force a reload of settings? I tried calling My.Settings.Default.Reload, however this did nothing. All settings are application settings, and only differ by "value" from those in the auto generated file.

I have successfully attached the debugger using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() and true enough, the settings are still the default settings.

In anticipation of the question, the background: The reason for requiring configuration settings is because this is a very straightforward service that simply executes an exe; and this exe is in configurable location. There are other reasons also, such as I wish to have the service name configurable without recompiling.

Comment: Note, I am pretty familiar with the My.Settings namespace, having used it many times in non-service apps. In this instance however it doesn't seem to work. As soon as practicable the only thing I can now think is to try ProcMon by SysInternals to see what files are being loaded. Any other suggestions most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that because the installer runs in the same process as InstallUtil.exe the config file is never found for a Windows Service. 
Similar article [here on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/896e110e-692d-4934-b120-ecc99b01c562)

Therefore I rolled my own simple solution inspired by [this](http://trycatch.me/installutil-windows-services-projectinstallers-with-app-config-settings/). See below for new code:

```
Friend Function GetConfigurationValue(ByVal key As String) As String
    Dim service = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(ProjectInstaller))
    Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(service.Location)
    Dim keyValue As String = config.AppSettings.Settings(key).Value

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValue) Then
        Throw New IndexOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Settings collection does not contain the requested key:[{0}]", key))
    End If

    Return keyValue
End Function
```

Alternative solutions:

[Passing parameters in to InstallUtil](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/SetupAndDeployment.aspx)
[Daenibuq (another abstraction on wrapping System.ServiceProcess)](http://code.google.com/p/daemoniq/)

Comment: Another solution might be to make your services be self installing (so that they, for example, can be called with -i to install and -u to uninstall) and then you don't have to worry about it being another process.

Answer (score 0):

When you're accessing the settings do you write `My.Settings.Default.MySetting`? If so, try changing that to `My.Settings.MySetting`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ho1, I already am accessing the setting as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you manually changed the settings in the app.config file. If so, these changes will only be picked up if they are `Application` settings - not `User` settings.

So the easy fix is to change your settings scope to `Application`.

### Update

Check your file access permissions. Does the account that the service is running under have permission to access the config file? See [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439334/windows-service-config-file-c/442539#442539)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Geoff, but the settings are all Application Settings

Comment: thanks Geoff, very logical suggestion. Alas this issue is exhibited even under the my login (ie the one that creates the file, service, and is the account that the service runs and is installed under).

Comment: @Topdown - Is the config file in the same folder as the executable(see "path to executable" in Windows Services properties dialog) or try copying it into the Windows.System32 folder. Don't forget to restart the service after making any changes.