# Using .xml with Windows Service c#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-services

I need to use XML for my service to read values that could be changed once it is running, and I can only find sources on people with problems with their current XML setup and literally nothing when it comes to beginners on it.

Could anyone explain briefly how to start using XML when it comes to designing a Windows Service or point me in the direction of a good source a beginner could make sense of?

Thanks

Comment: what exact difficulty are you facing when trying to work with Xml in a windows service?

Comment: Xml has no hate for Windows Service and no biased love for other kind of projects. Post what exactly you want to do with Xml  and what exact problem are you facing.

Comment: do you have an app.config for the values to go into?

Comment: The service I have made takes MSGID and CONTENT out of a .eml file and then creates another .eml file using given parameters - these parameters have to change now and then, but the service must stay running.

Comment: and I would also not know how to use App config

Comment: app.config with a service can be a bit of git anyway. same issues as another file with a bunch of visual studio assumptions on top. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439334/windows-service-config-file-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Xml has got nothing to do with windows service.

There are several Ways to use one in c# a simple one is the XmlDocument class.

e.g

```
XmlDocument configDoc = new XmlDocument();
configDoc.Load("ServiceConfig.xml");
XmlNode pollingNode = configDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("PollingInterval");
if (pollingNode != null)
{
/// Grab pollingNode.InnerText, convert to an int and set Property...
}
```

Above assumes xml is

```
<Config>
<PollingInterval>30</PollingInterval>
</Config>
```

Your big issue with this is where are you going to put the file, dealing with it being corrupted, some halfwit locking you out of it, it being deleted...

I'd have a think before going mental on this idea.

Comment: How else would I change the way a service runs at runtime?

Comment: @BenAshton Is there a reason they need to do it at runtime?  Many apps require you change the app.config file and then restart the service for changes to take effect.  There are tons of ways to change it at runtime if you want.  You could provide a GUI as a separate executable that communicates with the service via WPF.

Comment: @JohnKoerner seems to have answered that point. File is simple and possibly even a good start as a prototype, but implement it via an Interface, then you can use something where you donlt have to deal with it being missing/ broken or horror of horrors partially edited.

Comment: I have spoke to the person who needs it and apparently it the service can be restarted, do you know of any sources on this app.config thing? thanks!

Comment: Last comment on your question I posted a link to a question about C# Services and app.config

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML serialization if you would like.  This assumes a file called Demo.xml in the output directory:

```
string filePath = ".\\Demo.xml";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadSettings();
}

void ReadSettings()
{
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    Settings newSettings = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        try
        {
            newSettings = (Settings)s.Deserialize(sr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    if (newSettings != null)
        this.Text = newSettings.WatchPath;

}

public class Settings
{
    public string WatchPath { get; set; }
}
```

XML Format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <WatchPath>C:\Temp</WatchPath>
</Settings>
```

Comment: I get that, I mean more on what I can do - can I for example change the value of a varaible inside a xml and how would i do that?