# Acess Denied to installed application on Windows 8

Tags: c#, configuration

I've developed an application in `Visual Studio 2010` but I used the `VS 2012` to create the
`Setup Installer`. It's working `perfect` when running it on `Visual Studio 2012`, no errors at all.
`Detail: I builded this when I used win7, now i'm using windows 8`
But when I install the application and try to run it, when it tries to `overwrite the app.config` file it throws the exception. I already tried to give permission by `RightClick - Security tab` but didnt solve the problem. I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439334/windows-service-config-file-c-sharp) thread that looks like my problem. But didnt worked... All I have on my `app.config` is the connections strings. What may it be?

**UPDATE**
I gave permissions to `Users/PC1` in each `file.cfg` and to the whole folder that the files are in.
And now it seens that it worked, but what may I do to do not need do all of this to run the applpication ? I want to install without needing to give permission to the folders and files. (It's a win8 complications... -.- ).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permission issue, mostly with the project folder potentially.

You should try the following steps:

- Run Visual Studio as an `Administrator`.
- Verify that your `User Account` can `Read / Write` to your project folder.
- Ensure that your `Local Service`, `Network Service`, or `Local System`

Off the top of my head those would be what I would try, more then likely `Visual Studio` isn't able to modify your `app.config` which would be tied to your `Local Service` account- The one that would be tied to your *System*.

Though the inner content isn't the problem, it is tied to your *Directory Permissions* which may be inherited to the *sub-folders* and *sub-files*.

Hopefully that helps.