# Window service generates exception while reading 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString()'

Tags: c#

I am making a windows service.
It contain one App.config file as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SQLConnectionStr" value="Data Source=192.168.1.116;Initial Catalog=Conezone;User Id=sa;Password=saadmin@123;"/>
    <add key="FilePath" value="D:\Autoparts Guru\LINES2\"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

To get FilePath value in service code, I am writing

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString()
```

But it generates NullReferenceException.

Hope i get the answer quickly.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the App.config to web.config? I'm not sure app.config is properly handled by default in a web application.

Comment: do you have access to the SQLConnectionStr?

Comment: @Anton OP is talking about a Windows Service.

Comment: Is the exe you have made is itself registered as a service, or, are you running your exe via a service?

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah right, my bad.
Maybe this post can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439334/windows-service-config-file-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you:

***App.config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SQLConnectionStr" value="Data Source=000.000.000.000;Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=sa;Password=sa;"/>
    <add key="FilePath" value="myfilepath"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

***Namespace***

```
using System.Configuration;
```

***Code:***

```
string filepath = string.Empty;
filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
```

Comment: Explain what error you think OP made and how you corrected it. If `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString()` throws a NullReferenceException, then `"FilePath"` could not be read from the appSettings. Your config and code doesn't show any change there.

Comment: <startup> tag is automatically add when windows service created..You may miss up that

Comment: That section doesn't have any influence on `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. Please don't encourage voodoo / cargo cult.

Comment: Hey it have been solved. I just made one new service and paste all code from old service program and it works successfully.